# Doom Emacs > Haskel > What is the keyboard shortcut to evaluate a code block?

Tags: haskell, emacs

In Doom Emacs, Haskell code snippets placed after `-- >>>` can be evaluated using the mouse by clicking on the "Evaluate..." link. Is there a keyboard shortcut to do the same?

[image]

Comment: I believe this functionality is provided by lsp lens. I have also seeked for a way to trigger these buttons with a keyboard shortcut, but haven't found it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not currently (2022-04): there is an [open issue about it](https://github.com/haskell/haskell-language-server/issues/496). The essense of it is that there's a distinction between code lenses (visual decorations that you can point-and-click expecting code modifications) and code actions (code transformations). The Eval plugin for HLS currently only provides a code lens but not the corresponding code action.

Also note that this is not Doom specific or even Emacs specific, this is is shortcoming of the Haskell Language Server.

Comment: Thanks  for the comprehensive answer.

Comment: @Tharaka You bet!